# Wordpress - Pagination Broken on Search Page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

When I try to view Page 2 on the Search page it does not work because of a wrong permalink structure.

When using custom permalink structure %postname% it returns following url: /page/2/?s=adalya&post_type=product

When using simple permalink structure it returns: /?s=adalya&post_type=product&paged=2

So how can I make Wordpress rewrite the url correctly when custom permalink structure is activated?

Comment: Did you add any custom rewrite rules? `/page/2/?s=adalya&post_type=product` is correct url.

Comment: location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?args;}

This is the only rewrite rule in my nginx config.

Comment: I thought about WordPress rewrite rules (`add_rewrite_rule`, `add_rewrite_endpoint`, etc.) added in theme or plugin. What about pagination in other places (category page or custom post type archive)? It also does not work? Does the problem disappear after changing the theme or disabling the plugins?